# Modernizr for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, modernizr

I am having trouble with including modernizr for wordpress. I am using a child theme, btw. Can anyone help me out?

```html
function foundation_assets() {

    // Load JavaScripts
    wp_enqueue_script('add_jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('new_jquerypp', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquerypp.custom.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('bookblock', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.bookblock.js');
    //wp_enqueue_script('extra', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/extra.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('include_modernizr', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/modernizr.custom.js');

    //Load Stylesheet
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bookblock-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bookblock.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'foundation_assets' );
```

Here is my code for enqueuing it. It is saved in the functions.php.

Edited: Code has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

1) it's commented out

2) you are missing the closing parathesis.

`wp_enqueue_script('include_modernizr', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/modernizr.custom.js');`

Also take a look at the function definition to ensure your scripts will load in the right order https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

for example `wp_enqueue_script('new_jquerypp', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquerypp.custom.js', array('add_jquery'));` will make sure that `new_jquerypp` loads after jQuery itself

Comment: <div id="bb-bookblock" class="bb-bookblock">
 <div class="bb-item">
  <!-- CONTENT -->
 </div>
 <div class="bb-item">
  <!-- CONTENT -->
 </div>
</div>

Comment: This portion of the site won't display.